# getCharacterOffset() returns incorrect value

Tags: java, stax

I'm using StAX to parse an XML file and would like to know where each tag starts and ends. For that I'm trying to use `getLocation().getCharacterOffset()`, but it returns incorrect values for every tag beyond first.

```
XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(
        new StringReader("<root>txt1<tag>txt2</tag></root>"));

XMLEvent e;
e = reader.nextEvent(); // START_DOCUMENT
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(e.getLocation());
e = reader.nextEvent(); // START_ELEMENT "root"
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(e.getLocation());
e = reader.nextEvent(); // CHARACTERS "txt1"
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(e.getLocation());
e = reader.nextEvent(); // START_ELEMENT "tag"
System.out.println(e);
System.out.println(e.getLocation());
```

The code above prints this:

```
<?xml version="null" encoding='null' standalone='no'?>
Line number = 1
Column number = 1
System Id = null
Public Id = null
Location Uri= null
CharacterOffset = 0

<root>
Line number = 1
Column number = 7
System Id = null
Public Id = null
Location Uri= null
CharacterOffset = 6

txt1
Line number = 1
Column number = 12
System Id = null
Public Id = null
Location Uri= null
CharacterOffset = 11

<tag>
Line number = 1
Column number = 16
System Id = null
Public Id = null
Location Uri= null
CharacterOffset = 15
```

After `<root>` the `CharacterOffset` is correctly `6`, but then after `txt1` it is `11` while I expect to see `10`. What offset exactly does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug/feature of Sun/Oracle's StAX implementation.
With Woodstox, you get `0, 0, 6, 10`, which seems to be correct.
Download Woodstox from http://wiki.fasterxml.com/WoodstoxHome and
add the JARs (woodstox-core + stax2-api) to your class path. Then,
`XMLInputFactory` will automatically pick the Woodstox implementation.