# Java, XMLEvent location Characters

Tags: java, stax

I'm parsing the following String with a StAX XMLEventReader:

```
final String xmlstr = "<context><book><author>TheName</author></book></context>";
```

I'm observing the `event.getLocation().getCharacterOffset()` value and get some weird behavior: While the index for START_ELEMENT is reported at the position after the element declaration (e.g. index 9 for the context element), the CHARACTERS event for "TheName" is reported to be on index 32. Why? Is there a way to correct that?

Comment: That looks consistent, in that <context> ends 9 chars from the start, whilst your text element ends 32 chars from the start. Or have I miscounted ?

Comment: index 9 = '>' but index 32 = '/' and not 'e'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered a similar problem when going from the latest jdk6 to the latest jdk7. There seems to be a bug in com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl. [getCharacterOffset() returns incorrect value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656824/getcharacteroffset-returns-incorrect-value) suggests using a different XML parser.

(moved from comment to answer)

EDIT: I did some more systematic testing on this, and have found cases in jdk6 that are wrong and in jdk7 that are right and *also* vice versa. Interestingly, the line number and line column values appear to be consistent and correct across both jdk's.